# "Pad Left" with 0's on a char array

Tags: c#, arrays

G'day,

I have a char array that varies in size based on the length of some data. The array will never be larger than 24 though. It may however, be less than 24. As a result of this I need to "pad left" with 0's, as in add more elements to the left of the array to make it 24. I have below some code that does this, just wondering if there is a faster way or more efficient way to do so. Thanks!

*Note: I don't think this is a duplicate as I am working with char[]'s not strings.*

```
char[] dataLen = Convert.ToString(data.Length, 2).ToCharArray();
int j = 0;
char[] tmp = new char[24];
for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
{
     if (i < (24 - dataLen.Length))
          tmp[i] = '0';
     else
          tmp[i] = dataLen[j++];
}
dataLen = tmp;
```

Comment: why not simple `dataLen = data.PadLeft(24,'0').ToCharArray();`? What type _data_?

Comment: Can you not convert to a string, use String.PadLeft(), then convert back using .ToCharArray() ? Just to make it simpler code. I don't know how performant this needs to be.

Comment: @Grundy data is a char[] also, forgot to mention.

Comment: @VictorySaber I could do that I guess.

Comment: @Rhexis I should have added that as an answer. Can I at least get an upvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you simply use `String.PadLeft`?

```
 char[] data = "abcdefgh".ToCharArray(); // sample data
 data = new string(data).PadLeft(24, '0').ToCharArray();
```

That should be efficient and is also very readable.

Comment: Wow, thanks for this! This is it in one line: char[] dataLen = Convert.ToString(data.Length, 2).PadLeft(24, '0').ToCharArray();

Comment: Definitely shorter and more readable, but I have trouble seeing how it's going to be "faster" or "more efficient"

Comment: @KooKiz: i don't think that it's more efficient. But the point is that i don't see why OP's code is inefficient in the first place. But it's complexer than necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use a `string` for all operations, and use `PadLeft` to do the padding.

```
string input = new string(data);
string result = input.PadLeft(24, '0');
```

Then convert it to a `char[]` if you really need to:

```
char[] chars = result.ToCharArray();
```

(Also, your `Convert.ToString(data.Length, 2)` doesn't return their string representation, `new string(data)` does)

Comment: you, like me, also confusing with first param for `PadLeft` - first param -is _totalWidth_

Answer (score 1):

how about :

```
string z24 = "000000000000000000000";
tmp = z24.Take(24 - dataLen.Length).Union(dataLen).ToArray();
```